# Date format in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, date, azure

I have created a simple application build using asp.net MVC and SQL Server targeting the azure platform. My question is around date formatting. I have added a date picker which correctly uses dd/mm/yyy format. however when I pick the date I get the following validation error.

[image]

The project was build using database first. here is a screenshot of the property for that data item:

[image]

Where do I change the validation to accept dd/MM/yyyy. Also is there a way to set it so if there is a user in the US it will change date picker and validation to MM/dd/yyyy?

in both situations the date will be saved to the database as standard yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: Can you post your model

Comment: You haven't even told us which date picker plugin your using. Perhaps you could check its documentation

Comment: the problem is not dependent on the picker as it was happening when it was just a text field however in this case its Kendo UI

Answer (score 6):

Burn this into your brain:

`mm` is minutes.

`MM` is months.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is clearly with your date format. You are entering dates in the format of dd/MM/yyyy while the system is expecting MM/dd/yyyy.

1. Please check in your model whether you have specified any specific date formats.
2. Change the Ui culture of Kendo

Like this

```
    <script>
         //set current to the "en-GB" culture script
         kendo.culture("en-GB");
    </script>
```